# MySQL - How to select data by Character range (between min to max)

Tags: mysql, database

This question is regarding mysql. I want to get the only characters value  of min and max range. I think this is explained better with an example.
Example- The column of table is username like abc123 output should be 3,12de:-o/p->2,erogan44e :o/p->7 etc.
i want the select only characters length between min to max.

Is it possible without using procedure ?
Should we use regular expression ?

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of the letters ?

Comment: @  Hamza Abdaoui : yes

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of alphabets in a `String`, you first need to replace all the non-alphabet characters with an empty space and then calculate the length, e.g.:

```
SELECT LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '^[A-Za-z]', '')) AS value
FROM table
ORDER BY value DESC;
```

The problem with this approach is, MySQL does not have `REGEXP_REPLACE` function (unlike MariaDB). So, you will have to write your own function for this, have a look at [this](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/in-search-of-a-regex-replace-function-for-mysql.html) example.

Comment: @ Darshan Mehta: Thanks for answer.

Comment: If i count the numbers in a String, then should i used same way ? Otherwise you have any alternate way ?

Comment: Yes, it would be the same. If you just want to count the characters (i.e. not alphabets and/or numbers) then you can use `LENGTH` function straight away. However, if it's alphabets then you will need a user defined function.

Comment: @ritwik you can accept the answer if it has helped you.. :)